# How to iterate through a list inside a dictionary, and increment a variable inside the for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list which has a lot of numbers in each position:

`filteredFile = savgol_filter(filesInformationList["file3"], 41, 3)`

I have a function to find the peaks of that list:

```
x, y = find_peaks(filteredFile, height=2200, distance=400)
```

And then I have a for loop, which iterates through all those numbers and adds up to a variable, but for some reason in gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Duarte Arribas/Desktop/Documentos/fct 2017-2018/pyProjects/pyProject6/short-term/tableScript.py", line 38, in <module>
    sumOfAllValues += float(eachValue[peaksCount])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

the for loop (I'm sorry):

```
for aValue in range(0, len(filteredFile)):
    for eachValue in y["peak_heights"]:
        sumOfAllValues += float(eachValue[peaksCount])
        peaksCount += 1
    count2 += 1
```

**EDIT 2**

The data:

```
for fileName in glob.glob('*.txt'):
if fileName[0] != ".":
    fileToRead = open(fileName, "r")
    allLines = fileToRead.readlines()
    filesInformationList[f"file{count}"] = []
    for eachLine in allLines:
        if eachLine[0] != "#":
            allLinesSplitted = eachLine.split("\t")
            filesInformationList[f'file{count}'].append(int(allLinesSplitted[3]))
    count += 1
    print(count, "finished")
```

First numbers:

```
2939.53213139, 2303.18006894, 2473.44015882, 2470.17173524,
   2214.78218945, 2520.4469654 , 2383.29599895, 2372.14267638,
   2605.82521052, 2223.27605917, 2338.32117457, 2482.03905057,
   2438.21479995, 2402.16972817, 2405.29826781, 2376.0999171 ,
   2427.362494  , 2395.18081068, 2410.45159038, 2452.26318775,
   2417.66438326, 2411.38387364, 2389.91487412, 2439.28862516,
   2418.97901305, 2383.45172128, 2438.69588551, 2383.71700336,
   2424.22762773, 2451.33888913, 2413.42301148, 2366.29451547
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y['peak_heights']` is a series of scalars, which you unpack via a `for` loop. But then you *index* the scalar with an integer counter. You can't index a scalar.

You can just iterate over the series directly. This will make `peaksCount` redundant:

```
for eachValue in y['peak_heights']:
    sumOfAllValues += float(eachValue)
```

This is still anti-pattern and non-vectorised. Instead, you can use `pd.Series.sum`:

```
sumOfAllValues += y['peak_heights'].sum()
```

Note this will not guarantee your program works as intended; it only clarifies how you can overcome the specific error you have identified.